# How to debug the PHP warning "Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement"?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my PHP code for Android login register app, am getting this in my server address:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-result]:
>   Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared
>   statement in /home/a6546950/public_html/FetchUserdetails.php on line
>   15

Here is the PHP:

```
<? php

$con = mysqli_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$name = $_POST["name"];
$collegename = $_POST["collegename"];
$batch = $_POST["batch"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM LoginList WHERE username =  ? AND password =?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $name, $collegename, $batch, $username, $password);

$LoginList = array();

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
    $LoginList[name] = $name;
    $LoginList[collegename] = $collegename;
    $LoginList[batch] = $batch;
    $LoginList[username] = $username;
    $LoginList[password] = $password;
}
echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Now that your database credentials are public, please change them for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is exactly what the error says. You are binding onto 5 variables (`$name`, `$collegename`, `$batch`, `$username`, `$password`) using `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`. Your query is likely selecting more (or possibly less) fields than 5.

Comment: i tried reducing variables,but its not helping.

Comment: @sunnyjoel How many columns does your table have?

Comment: 6 columns,but first column is the id column using auto increment.

Comment: @sunnyjoel That is your problem then. You are trying to bind to 5 columns but you are selecting 6. You'll either need to also bind to the id column or, preferably, only `SELECT` the columns that you want to use.

Comment: yeah the warning disppeared,but its showing                                          null                                                                                                                in the address,isthat right?

Comment: @sunnyjoel I don't see anywhere in the code that you use address so I can't say.